# Remove \listoffigures and \listoftables from Table of Contents in mwcls

Tags: table-of-contents, mwcls

I've been trying out the `mwcls` classes (mwarticle, mwrep, mwbk), which seem to have a quite Spartan, but nevertheless pleasant, design overall. But I can't figure out how to remove  \listoffigures and \listoftables from the Table of Contents. (The tocbibind package does not seem to work.)

A MWE could be

```
\documentclass{mwbk}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables


\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:frog}Frog.}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
Item & Quantity \\
\midrule
Widgets & 42 \\
Gadgets & 13\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to `mwbook.cls`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, sorry the correct name is `mwbk`. I could find one at `http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/misc/tex/common/teTeX-1.0.1/lib/texmf/tex/latex/mwcls/mwbk.cls`

Comment: Nevermind. The class is `mwbk` and not `mwbook` as you had before the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX writes all entries into the `.toc` file and counter `tocdepth` controls, which entry levels are included. Therefore temporary changes of `tocdepth` must be set in the `.toc` file.

The following example writes two actions into the `.toc` file before `\listoffigures`:

- The current value of `tocdepth` is saved in macro `\SavedTocDepth`.
- `tocdepth` is assigned a larger negative value to disable the inclusion of
  `\chapter`s and friends.

After `\listoftables` an action is written to the `.toc` file to restore the counter `tocdepth` with the value saved in `\SavedTocDepth`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{mwbk}

\newcommand*{\BeginNoToc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \edef\protect\SavedTocDepth{\protect\the\protect\value{tocdepth}}%
  }%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\EndNoToc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\protect\SavedTocDepth}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\BeginNoToc

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\EndNoToc

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\label{fig:frog}Frog.}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Summary}
\end{document}
```

The `.toc` file contains:

```
\edef \SavedTocDepth {\the \value {tocdepth}}
\setcounter {tocdepth}{-10}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Figures}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{5}
\setcounter {tocdepth}{\SavedTocDepth }
\contentsline {chapter}{Chapter\ 1\relax .\kern .5em Introduction}{7}
\contentsline {chapter}{Chapter\ 2\relax .\kern .5em Summary}{9}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: When I do this it removes all the entries from \listoffigures and \listoftables. I think it's easier to remove the entries from the .toc file and compile just once.

Comment: @Joseph Sorry, I have now updated and corrected the answer, the previous version was quite wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although Heiko's answer seems to work, I've managed to come up with a solution changing `\chapter@toc` from the class itself:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
\ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%\fi
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    %\ifHeadingNumbered
    \mw@seccntformat{\@chapapp\ \HeadingNumber}\HeadingTOCText%
    %\fi
    }\fi %added \fi here
%\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}

\makeatother
```