# remove \listoffigures \listoftables \listofplots from table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I want remove `\listoffigures \listoftables \listofplots` from my `\tableofcontents`
I found [**this**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272070/remove-listoffigures-and-listoftables-from-table-of-contents-in-mwcls) solution but I want a permanent solution for my custom class, which remove those list for other dudes who use class.

you can find class file [here](https://github.com/iausirjan/Latex/blob/master/IAUSIRJAN-THESIS.cls)

and I have [extra commands file too](https://github.com/iausirjan/Latex/blob/master/commands.tex)

and code for my `\listoflots` is :

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lop,
  listname={فهرست نمودارها},
name=نمودار,
%  name=Plot,
  placement=tp,
  %within=section,% activate it if you want
  %chapterlistsgaps=on,% only meaningful when chapters exist
]{plot}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example instead ofvrelying on external code.

Comment: You should also check out package tocbibind

Comment: `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` are usually *not* included in the ToC by default, so the fact that they are, is because of a specific choice you have made. In particular, the addition of `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. The only purpose of that package is to add things like `\listoffigures` to the ToC.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  yes `nottoc` was in project. thanks